# Proving the independence or not of events in a Bernoulli probability space

Tags: probability, measure-theory

The measure space $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)=(\Omega, \mathcal{E}, \mathbb{P})$ is the Bernoulli probability space, where

$\Omega=\{(\omega_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}} | \omega_j \in \{u,d\}   \forall j \in \mathbb{N}\}$

and $\mathcal{E}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the simple events $E_n=\{(\omega_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \in \Omega | \omega_n=u\}, n \in \mathbb{N}$. Determine whether the sequence $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of events in $\mathcal{E}$ defined by

$A_n=E_n^c \cap E_{n+3}, n\in \mathbb{N}$

is an independent sequence of events.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like this is trivially true by looking at $A_n$ and $A_{n+3}$.

Independent events means $\mathbb{P}(A_n \cap A_m)= \mathbb{P}(A_n)\mathbb{P}(A_m)$ for any $m,n \in \mathbb{N},m \ne n$, and since $A_{n+3}$ has $\omega_{n+3}=d$, and $A_n$ has $\omega_{n+3}=u$,

$$
\mathbb{P}(A_n \cap A_{n+3})=0
$$

for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, but $\mathbb{P}(A_i) = p(1-p) >0$ for $i \in \mathbb{N}$ where $p=P(\omega_j = u)$ in $E_n$ for $j \ne n \in \mathbb{N}$, so the sequence of events is not independent.